# What is the salesforce turnaround time for API usage refresh

Tags: api

We have just exceeded our API usage limit. Need to check when will be the turnaround time for the refreshment. I think it is refreshed hourly but can't find the related document.

Is there any document stating this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a moving window - last 24 hours. If you've been doing callouts for the last 24 hours continuously, chances are you can make more callouts in a few minutes, as the ones older 24 hours will stop count. Though, if you made all the callouts in the last 5 minutes and you've exceeded the limit, then you'll have to wait 24 hours before you can make more callouts. So the limit applies to callouts made within that 24h window.

[Documentation](http://resources.docs.salesforce.com/210/14/en-us/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet.pdf) (Page 35):

> The DebuggingHeader has an extra usage limit of 1,000 calls per
> 24-hour period.
>
> Limits are enforced against the aggregate of all API
> calls made to the org in a 24-hour period. Limits are not on a
> per-user basis. When an org exceeds a limit, all users in the org can
> be temporarily blocked from making additional calls. Calls are blocked
> until usage for the preceding 24 hours drops below the limit.
>
> For Unlimited Edition and  Performance  Edition orgs, it ’ s likely that
> other limiting factors, such as system load, can prevent you from
> using your entire allocation of calls in a 24-hour period.

Comment: And dev console eats a lot of calls. Have to be careful in DE orgs with limited API call limits